# How to Connect Sharepoint Online to MySQL server database

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have been trying to connect my MYSQL server to Sharepoint so Sharepoint list will automatically sync to mysql. Any answers would be greatly appreciated. Willing to use other databases as long I am able to get a database up and running and synced with Sharepoint List.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online cannot directly connect to on-premise sql server.

Here are some options for you:

1.SQL Azure:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28286.office-365-sharepoint-online-bcs-with-azure-sql-server-database.aspx

2.Use  Azure Hybrid Connections:https://asishpadhy.com/2018/01/19/getting-on-premises-data-from-sql-to-sharepoint-online-using-azure-hybrid-connections/

3.Create custom WCF service: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service

References:

https://www.peters.com/blog/exposing-sql-data-sharepoint-online/